# How can I set just one property of an embedded document when creating an instance of a document?

Tags: mongoose

I am making an instance of a document which has a sub-document. I want to set one property of the sub-document, and let the rest of its properties be assigned their default values. I thought I could just do it like this:

```
document = new Document({
  subDocument.property1: body.property1
})
```

But that causes an "unexpected token" error. Is it possible to do this? I've been unable to find an answer in the Mongoose docs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it achieved what I wanted:

```
document = new Document({
  subDocument: {property1: body.property1}
})
```

The other properties of subDocument still got set to their defaults, which is what I wanted.